# Getting undefined method oid when loading the db definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm migrating a Rails application from 4.2 to 5.0 using PostgreSQL as database.

When preparing the db for running the test suite with

```
bundle exec rails db:schema:load
```

I'm getting this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `oid' for #ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::ColumnDefinition:0x00007fe538e3adf8

After a bit of digging, I found out the problem was when I set a `default` option in the columns definition.

Here is what the `schema.rb` looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20210111100855) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  enable_extension "pg_stat_statements"

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "namespace"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace", using: :btree
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
...
end
```

And I'm using Postgresql 13.1.

Have you already encountered this error? How did you fix it?

Comment: Can you add your schema.rb to the question?

Comment: Also, what Postgres version are you using?

Comment: I added those 2 details to the question.